# labeling data by travel time to a point

Tags: mysql, algorithm, data-structures, data-analysis

At work, I have been tasked to find a way to label our data by approximate travel time.

Our website is a place where users can place ads for real estate properties, for rent/sale.

So each Ad entity has latitude, longitude, some information about the ad and so on.

We want to label for example ads that are close to universities, highway entry points, sea, schools, Let's call these points of interest(POI).

We have about 800k ads on our website, and about 1k new ads every day.

In order to get the travel time we can use Open Trip Planner to create an isochrone of a point of interest then we get back polygons for example of locations that are 15 minutes away by public transportation.

So it's possible to check which ads are inside those polygons and tag them to be near the POI. But we could have 10k POI (1 for each school, kindergarten, etc ) and for each isochrone query you get like 10+ polygons at least,
and that is just for public transportation, We will need one for other types of travel(Walking, Car, Bicycle), let's say 4 and each isochrone query takes about 500ms to generate from OTP.

As you can see numbers are getting quite big, And we are having trouble finding the best solution, Also we think that maybe there is a better solution than using OTP to get the approximate travel time.

Also we have the latitude and longitude of each address in the country which is about 750k entries, So it is possible to label the addresses instead, and then point each ad to an address.

So I have two questions

1. Would you use OTP for this task, Or do you know a solution out of a box for this kind of problem?
2. How would you design your database and what would be the best algorithm to tag the data considering current mentioned issues?

**The end result would be to be able to display to the user something like
"This property is a 10 minutes walk from the sea" for example.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your application’s points of interest do not change as often as your listings.

So you could exploit the [geospatial extension](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html) in MySQL to build an isochrone table.

Each point of interest might have four rows in the table, one each for 5, 10, 15, and 20 minute walks. The isochrone itself in each row can be represented as a POLYGON object.

You would populate these rows infrequently, whenever you added a new POI or when traffic patterns changed, with OTP information.

Then when you add a new listing, you can use that table to look up nearby POIs and trip times.

If the cost of using OTP is not too high, you could simply use it each time you add a new listing. That way you can avoid making the isochrone table.

If you create the correct indexes, this sort of application is well within the capabilities of your DBMS.

Do use the latest version of the dbms.  And do investigate postgreSQL: its geospatial features are more mature than MySQL’s.